# .NET IBM DB2BulkCopy - Determine if Error Caused Failed Insert

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, db2

The following is a function I am using to do a bulk Insert into DB2. The Errors property of the DB2BulkCopy class returns a DB2ErrorsCollection (see my local variable errorCollection). The problem is, the only errors I care about are the ones that would prevent a row from being inserted into the table.

An example of an error I'm getting that I *don't* care about is 01517 - "A character that could not be converted was replaced with a substitute character." This is returned in the DB2ErrorCollection object but I don't care about it.

Is there a way to filter out only errors that would have prevented a row from being inserted?

```
public static DB2ErrorCollection RunDb2BulkCopy(DB2Connection conn, DataTable table, string tableName)
{
    DB2ErrorCollection errorCollection;

    using (var bc = new DB2BulkCopy(conn))
    {
        //Have to provide column mappings below - requirement. This code assumes that the DataTable and
        //the DB2 table have the same column names.
        foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns)
        {
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add(new DB2BulkCopyColumnMapping(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName));
        }

        bc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        bc.WriteToServer(table);

        errorCollection = bc.Errors;
    }

    return errorCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLSTATE values (for example 01517) have the first two characters indicating the classification or class-code.

'00' is success.

'01' in your case is a warning.

other values of the class code are errors you probably should not ignore.

The full list of class codes is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html) and it has links to tables that enumerate each code per class-code.

There may be language-level classes/sub-classes to handle such matters.